# Why does a DataGridView crash

Tags: datagridview

If I run this code first...

```
        private void offToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvOff in dgv_Off.Rows)
        {
            dgvOff.Cells[0].Value = 0;
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvOn in dgv_On.Rows)
        {
            dgvOn.Cells[0].Value = 0;
        }
    }
```

Then I run this code my app crashes.

```
        private void dgv_Off_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_Off.SelectedRows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
                {
                    row.Cells[0].Value = !(bool)row.Cells[0].Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.Cells[0].Value = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's crashing at this line.

```
row.Cells[0].Value = !(bool)row.Cells[0].Value;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error? From the line you point to… I can only guess that you may get a casting exception… which means the cell’s value is not a Boolean value.... `(bool)row.Cells[0].Value` ...

Comment: Hi JohnG Based on your reply I changed the offending line to                         row.Cells[0].Value = !Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value); and that stopped the crashing. Do you know why the first block of code which is supposed to uncheck all rows works on all rows except one?

Comment: The one that won't change is the last one that I previously manually selected. Somehow that's retained.

Comment: added dgv_Off.EndEdit(); after the if statement in the second block of code and it fixed my second problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction JohnG.